# Calling javascript function on onMouseOut

Tags: javascript, html, marquee

I wrote the following code, for marquee:
In which I want on mouse-over, a function will get called

```
<marquee class="smooth_m" behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="3">
  <span style="float:left; padding:0 20px 0 0;" onMouseOut="loadStart()" onMouseOver="loadStop()">testing</span>
</marquee>
<script type="text/javascript">
loadStop()
{
alert("loadStop");  
}
loadStart()
{
alert("loadStart"); 
}
</script>
```

but it's not loading the respective functions in span like, onMouseOut it should load loadStart and so on..
Can someone help in this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery. In simple JavaScript language you should use `function` keyword to define a function.

Comment: Keep in mind that the `mouseout` even is fired whenever the mouse cursor moves out of any element, including the inner `<span>` of your `<marquee>`, and it bubbles up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/CTQVr/ **or** on mouse over stop marquee like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CTQVr/4/

issues was: function missing from your function name.

Hope this helps,

**HTML**

```
<marquee class="smooth_m" behavior="scroll" direction="left" scrollamount="3">
  <span style="float:left; padding:0 20px 0 0;" onmouseout="loadStart()" onmouseover="loadStop()"> testing</span>
</marquee>

​
```

**jquery code**

```
function loadStop() {
    alert("loadStop");
}

function loadStart() {
    alert("loadStart");
}​
```

**Update** to stop on mouseover

```
$("marquee").hover(function () { 
    this.stop();
   // loadStop();
}, function () {
    this.start();
   // alert("loadStart");
});
​
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there any way that I can stop or start the marquee from loadStop or loadStart functions? (using jquery)

Comment: Hiya @MohanSinfh yep indeed see here and I am updating my answer as well :) **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/CTQVr/4/ hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
function loadStop()
{
    alert("loadStop");  
}
function loadStart()
{
    alert("loadStart"); 
}
```

The function keyword is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You miss function in you function definition, try something like:

```
function loadStop()
{
alert("loadStop");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `hover` method instead of using html event handlers:

```
$('span').hover(function(){
     alert('LoadStops')
},function(){
    alert('LoadStarts')
})
```